# Django - Authentication in Forms

Tags: python, django

I'm relatively new to Django and most of what I've done previously hasn't needed User Authentication so I am especially new to working with this.

I have two of my own models, a company (linked to a django user), and employees (many to one relationship with a company).

What I would like to do is find out how to create forms so that when a user is logged in, it can add new employees that are automatically tethered to the company relating to that user (and cannot tether them to others of course).

I've seen things like self.request(user), but am unsure how this would work for me as the model I am trying to create with this form is not directly linked to the user that is logged in.

Any advice or pointers towards places with solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not too sure about how your models are set up but maybe something like `self.request.user.company.employee_set.all()` might help? that would return all of the employee's for the company the user belongs to

Comment: This might help https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html

Comment: Hi @RHSmith, yes I've managed to user a similar method from the Mozille Django tutorial so I can view all employees tethered to a company from a user. However I'm unsure as to how, with a new employee form, to make sure the  company can only be and is automatically set as the one of the user that is logged in.

Comment: so if I understand correctly, you want a user to be able to login, and create employee records (through a new employee form) for the company they belong to?

Comment: Yeah, apologies for the convoluted explanation I was unsure how to word it. Essentially the flow of use would be - user logs in, navigates to a 'my company' section, from which it can add employees.

Comment: ok great thanks for the clarification, I'll make an answer now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing too much about how your models are setup. This may help:

Login form:

```
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):

    username = forms.CharField(required = True)
    password = forms.CharField(required = True)
```

Your Login View:

```
from .forms import LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

def login_view(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

        login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if login_form.is_valid():

            cleaned_username = login_form.cleaned_data["username"]
            cleaned_password = login_form.cleaned_data["password"]

            user = authenticate(username = cleaned_username, password = cleaned_password)

             # It might be worth putting the form processing into a method of the login form.


             if user:

                 login(user)

                 return redirect("url_for_my_company_page")

             else:

                 pass # user failed auth, send message back to user

        else:

            pass # form not valid, handle errors

        else:

            login_form = LoginForm()


    return render(request, "template.html", {"login_form":login_form}
```

Now when your user successfully logs in, they are redirected to their company page. This means when you use `request.user` you will get the authenticated user. (Otherwise I think it returns an 'AnonymousUser').

Your Company View:

```
def my_company_view(request):

    user_company = request.user.company

    # here you can put in your new_employee form
    # the user_company can now be used


    return render(request, "template.html", {"company": user_company}
```

If  you are using a model form (`models.ModelForm`) for your new employee form, I think you can add variables into the form through the constructor:

```
class NewEmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, company, *args, **kwargs):
        self.company = company
        super(NewEmployeeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['company'].initial = company

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        #fields...

    def save(self):
        Employee.objects.create(company = self.company)
```

If you are just using a generic form (`forms.Form`) you will be able to just set the employee's company using the `user_company` variable.

Hope this helps!